# (Physics) Animated Model with Armature interacts with cloth, but not other objects

Tags: animation, armature, physics

I cannot find a answer to my problem.

The armature-animated model interacts perfectly with cloth physics, but will not interact with a physics-based cube.  I cannot find a answer to this problem.  Please help.

Cube: Active + Dynamic

Cloth: Active + Dynamic

Model: Passive + Animated

For some reason the cloth hits the cube but not the model itself.  Why?!

**I just want the model to be able to push the cube off by turning.**

[image]

Comment: Check the modifier stack, they are applied from top down, the armature needs to deform the mesh before the physics collision.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out, apparently this had something to do with it...

[image]